Edge ground loop on a PCB
I recently added a ground edge on my PCB to reject EMI noise on. Adding this ground loop have a strong effect on rejecting EMI noise:

My PCB is a 12-layer board, currently I have this ground loop on the edge just on layer 1 and layer 12 (top and bottom). My question is should I have this ground loop on all the layers from layer 1 to layer 12 (Top and bottom + inner layers)? Or it is just enough to have it on the top and bottom layer?
(Regarding the loop, in fact it is not a loop because it is connected in bottom layer, we have one break on top, but we do not have it on the bottom layer, and we have another break on the bottom layer in another location, but we don not have it on the top layer.)
Stack up:
(Sig-1, Gnd, Sig-2, Gnd, PWR1, Gnd, PWR2, Gnd, Sig-3, Gnd, Gnd, Sig-4)
I have used many vias on the edge to connect top and bottom edge to each other, then I have just connected the edge loop at one point to the input GND.

"Adding this ground loop have a strong effect" -- what effect? Show emissions plots comparing with vs. without. How is it connected (shield? enclosure?)?  What are your layers assigned as? What traces are routed in the area?

Breaking the loop is likely to make it a better antenna, not what you want.

@Tim Williams without this loop we could see a lot of un wanted noise when we probe the out outputs of the amplifiers, but with this loop and a metal enclosure conduced to the loop the unwanted noise was very smaller, there are 12 layers, Sign-1, Gnd, Sig-2, Gnd, PWR1, Gnd, PWR2, Gnd, Sig-3, Gnd, Gnd, Sig-4

@ John Doty in fact it is not a loop because it is connected in bottom layer, we have one break on top, but we do not have it on the bottom layer, and we have another break on the bottom layer in another location, but we don not have it on the top layer.

The guard line allows better control of capacitive coupling between the sides of the PCB and the surrounding environment (the metal case and what's inside), but a reasonable distance between the sides of the PCB and the surrounding environment has much the same effect.This guard line around a floating GND can improve the immunity of your electronics, especially if your metal case contains other elements likely to generate inductive coupling (power supply, for example).

Is it connected to signal ground or external chassis ground? In either case breaking up the loop makes no sense.

@Lundin it is connected to the power supply input connector GND pin.
